# react style-component styles not being applied

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

The styles in this component are not applied. Following the exact same pattern in other components works just fine. I can't figure out why. When the app is reloaded, there are no styles or name applied to the divs. If I adjust the css and save the app, the hot reload then shows the styles.

```
const Orders:FC = ():ReactElement => {

  return(
    <StyledControls>
        <StyledIcon><FaIcon icon={'ThLarge'} /></StyledIcon>
        <StyledIcon><FaIcon icon={'ThList'} /></StyledIcon>
    </StyledControls>    
  )
}

const StyledControls = styled.div`
  display:flex;
  width:5em;
`;

const StyledIcon = styled.div`
  width:3em;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline;
  color:#CCC;
`;
```

Comment: If this is your code, try moving styles components styles before the function `Orders:FC`. In your app this is the only case that dosn't work? Maybe you are missing the webpack loader or something?

Comment: I think that if it was a webpack issue, then it would affect all files.